# How to construct sequential ID logic

Tags: c#, sequential

I got an textbox1.text="J001" when the form "insert" is showed up. there's a button in "insert" so if we click that button, mbox said "J001 is added".

But then, I want to change the textbox.text = "J002"; so I'm using.

`string splitter=textbox1.text.toString().subString(1)`

It will return 001. and now what do i have to make it 002? I can't +1 on it though, in additional, I'm not using any database, so it will become "J001" again when we close the form, and reopen them. click the button, the text become "J002". close the form, reopen, it shows "J001" and infinite loop.

Comment: Is it always J001, J002, or could it be X001, X002, or perhaps even LONGLONG001, LONGLONG002?

Comment: yes it will be a static J001 J002 J003 J004 Jxxx and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite difficult to understand what you want, but maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
string splitter = textbox1.Text.ToString().Substring(1);

try {
    int number = Convert.ToInt32(splitter) + 1;
} catch (FormatException e) {
    // Not a number...
}

textbox1.Text = String.Format("J{0}", number.ToString());
```

Comment: The number should be '0' left padded.

Comment: You don't need to trim the 0s.  001 is a valid number literal anyway.

Comment: I did mean in the final output; your code, if started with J001, will output in textbox J2 instead of J002. It should be "J{0:000}" instead of "J{0}".

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of your number with a static variable, then simply format the text and bump the counter by 1.  If you're closing the application and restarting it, the counter will start over.  If you want it to persist, you'll have to save the value somewhere like a database.

```
static int _counter = 0;

...

textbox1.Text = string.Format("J{0,2}", ++_counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: it will handle variable length prefix and variable length number (up to the length of a long, so 19 digits).

First it counts the number of digits after the prefix, then it replaces those digits with the incremented value.

```
string str = "J9999";

int firstDigit = str.Length;

for (; firstDigit > 0; firstDigit--)
{
    if (!char.IsDigit(str[firstDigit - 1]))
    {
        break;
    }
}

if (firstDigit < str.Length)
{
    long num = long.Parse(str.Substring(firstDigit));
    num++;

    int numOfDigits = str.Length - firstDigit;
    var temp = num.ToString("D" + numOfDigits);

    //Uncomment this for fixed length with overflow: J999->J000, otherwhise you have J999->J1000
    //temp = temp.Substring(temp.Length - numOfDigits);

    str = str.Remove(firstDigit) + temp;
}
```